# Onclick Event (ANDROID STUDIO)

Tags: android-fragments, android-intent

What's wrong with my code. I got an error "cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)". Fragment is the new package. Without the button code part, it works perfectly.

```
public class Scanner1 extends Fragment {

    private Button scannerButton;
    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_main,container,false);
         return rootView;


        scannerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scannerButton);

        scannerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BarcodeScanner.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment doesn't has findViewById. You Must Using Your rootView

```
public class Scanner1 extends Fragment {

    private Button scannerButton;
    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_main,container,false);

        scannerButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.scannerButton);

        scannerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BarcodeScanner.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

      return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: change to scannerButton = (Button)rootView.(R.id.scannerButton); still the same.

Comment: its "cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)" ?!?

Comment: Error:(42, 6) error: reached end of file while parsing